# ng repeat index doesn't work for jade mixin

Tags: angularjs, pug

I'm using `angularJS 1.5.8` ng-repeat with an array of search data. I tried to pass the `$index` on mixin inside ng-repeat. It showed empty. When I declared variable object through $scope inside controller and pass to Mixin, it worked with variable, but `$index` doesn't.

**Jade**

```
ul
 li(ng-repeat='p in searchData')
   span
    | Before Mixin: $index
   +AddItem($index)
```

**Mixin**

```
mixin AddItem($index)
  span
   | Inside Mixin: {{ $index }}
```

**Output**

```
Before Mixin: 0
Inside Mixin:
Before Mixin: 1
Inside Mixin:
```

Comment: Do you mean `| Inside Mixin: #{$index}`?

Comment: @sean I tried that, but doesn't work. Show empty.

Comment: And your mixin is in the same pug file or is properly included?

Comment: @sean property included